# javascript not including files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

I'm having trouble trying to use a function in a javascript file I've included in another file upon starting up the page.

Within the file design.js I want to do var x = new canvasManager(); And canvasManager is defined in canvasManager.js.

However when I try this I get some 'uncaught type error undefined is not a function'. What gives? Below is the relevant code on my html file that I enter into the browser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/kinetic.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="designManager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasManager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gateManager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wireManager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="toolbarManager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="objectDrawing.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="util/mouseEventManager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="util/hotkeyManager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="util/htmlUtils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="design.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      initializeDesign(); 
  });
</script>
```

//in design.js...

```
function initializeDesign() {

    var canvasManager = new canvasManager();

}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: what does canvasManager.js look like?

Comment: Is there any way to consolidate those JS files?

Comment: Check the path is correct or not. use this firefox toolbar https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/ and  goto >> information >> View Javascript to see all javascript included. The missing ones will show page not found error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `canvasManager` in `new canvasManager()` is referring to the `canvasManager` in `var canvasManager`, not the `canvasManager` that you have defined in other JS file. The declaration of `canvasManager` in `initializeDesign()` shadows the other declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your variable in:

```
 var canvasManager = new canvasManager();
```

When you define that local variable, it supercedes the global function with the same name so that `new canvasManager()` just refers to your local variable not to the global function.  Thus, since the value of the local variable is still undefined, you get the error you see.

Change it to:

```
 var theCanvasManager = new canvasManager();
```

or something like that and it should work fine.

---

Though I wouldn't recommend this (because I think it's not super readable code and could lead to other accidental errors), you could also do this:

```
 var canvasManager = new window.canvasManager();
```

Here you are explicitly referring to the globally-scoped function so it's distinct from the local variable.